# Joining multiple tables in MySQL: "Unknown column"

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running into an error with a simple `JOIN` in MySQL. Am I missing something obvious?

```
SELECT stop_times.stop_sequence
FROM stop_times
INNER JOIN stops ON stop_times.stop_id = stops.stop_id
INNER JOIN trips ON stop_times.trip_id = trips.trip_id
WHERE stops.stop_code = :stopCode;
```

Where `:stopCode` is a parameter that is bound via PDO.

The error I'm getting is: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'stop_times.trip_id' in 'on clause''`

The database schema for these three tables are:

```
stop_times
----------
trip_id VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL -- PK
arrival_time TIME NOT NULL
departure_time TIME NOT NULL
stop_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL -- PK
stop_sequence INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL -- PK


stops
-----
stop_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL -- PK
stop_code INT(5) UNSIGNED NULL
stop_name VARCHAR(53) NOT NULL
stop_lat DECIMAL(8, 6) NOT NULL
stop_lon DECIMAL(9, 6) NOT NULL
stop_url VARCHAR(66) NULL

trips
-----
route_id INT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
service_id VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
trip_id VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL -- PK
trip_headsign VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
```

I've also tried using aliases but that didn't work. Running the query in Microsoft Access works, the SQL that is produced has brackets around the JOIN statements though.

Why is my query not working?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are running the query you posted? The error looks like the query is using an alias for `stop_times`

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make a typo and put st.trip_id in the SQL code?  You don't have any aliases in the code you gave us...

Comment: I don't see `st.trip_id` in the query you posted

Comment: create a sqlfiddle and try to reproduce ... i bet you find your mistake, wherever it is

Comment: Sorry, I copied the error from when I was using aliases. It's still giving me the error with the table name, aliased or not.

Comment: Have you try to run it directly in phpMyAdmin? Is it working?

Comment: @FabienTheSolution Yes I've tried in there as well, same error.

Comment: Have you see what @Michael Fredrickson pointed out in his answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you using back ticks (`` `)in your actual query to escape the table / column names, but stripping them out of your question?  I'm guessing yes, because they probably gave you some formatting issues since Stack Overflow uses them to escape code blocks...

My guess is that you meant to write:

```
INNER JOIN `trips` ON `stop_times`.`trip_id` = `trips`.`trip_id`
```

But instead, you wrote:

```
INNER JOIN `trips` ON `stop_times.trip_id` = `trips`.`trip_id`
```

Since you're missing a pair of back ticks, it gets treated as a single column name, giving you the following error:

> Unknown column 'stop_times.trip_id' in 'on clause': SELECT
>   stop_times.stop_sequence FROM stop_times INNER JOIN stops ON
>   stop_times.stop_id = stops.stop_id INNER JOIN trips ON
>   `stop_times.trip_id` = trips.trip_id WHERE stops.stop_code = 1

### [SQL Fiddle Showing the Assumed Mistake](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/eb0f7/1)

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason why this is not working based on what you provided :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb978/1)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
create table stop_times (
trip_id VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL,
arrival_time TIME NOT NULL,
departure_time TIME NOT NULL,
stop_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
stop_sequence INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);


create table stops (
stop_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
stop_code INT(5) UNSIGNED NULL,
stop_name VARCHAR(53) NOT NULL,
stop_lat DECIMAL(8, 6) NOT NULL,
stop_lon DECIMAL(9, 6) NOT NULL,
stop_url VARCHAR(66) NULL);

create table trips (
route_id INT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
service_id VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
trip_id VARCHAR(23) NOT NULL,
trip_headsign VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);   

INSERT INTO stop_times
    (trip_id, arrival_time, departure_time, stop_id, stop_sequence)
VALUES
    ('TRIP_ID', '09:00', '09:30', 1, 1)
;

INSERT INTO stops
    (stop_id, stop_code, stop_name, stop_lat, stop_lon, stop_url)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'NAME', 1.3, 2.4, 'www.url.com')
;

INSERT INTO trips
    (route_id, service_id, trip_id, trip_headsign)
VALUES
    (1, 'SRV_ID', 'TRIP_ID', 'HEADSIGN')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT stop_times.stop_sequence
FROM stop_times
INNER JOIN stops ON stop_times.stop_id = stops.stop_id
INNER JOIN trips ON stop_times.trip_id = trips.trip_id
WHERE stops.stop_code = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb978/1/0)**:

```
| STOP_SEQUENCE |
|---------------|
|             1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

As Fabien TheSolution points out, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your query as you lay out your question. You can see an error like that when you mix explicit and implicit joins (ANSI-92 versus ANSI-89).

Is it possible your simplified the query for posting? The error you have could make sense if your query looked something like this with one explicit join and one implicit or natural join:

```
SELECT stop_times.stop_sequence
FROM stop_times, stops
INNER JOIN trips ON stop_times.trip_id = trips.trip_id
WHERE stop_times.stop_id = stops.stop_id AND stops.stop_code = :stopCode
```

Also does your query work with all natural joins:

```
SELECT stop_times.stop_sequence
FROM stop_times, stops, trips
WHERE stop_times.stop_id = stops.stop_id 
  AND stop_times.trip_id = trips.trip_id
  AND stops.stop_code = :stopCode
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using aliases without giving them a name , that is why you are getting the error try use something as following in your query.

```
  SELECT a.stop_sequence
  FROM (
    SELECT st.stop_sequence, st.trip_id, s.stop_code
    FROM stop_times st
    INNER JOIN stops s ON st.stop_id = s.stop_id
       )a
INNER JOIN trips ON a.trip_id = trips.trip_id
WHERE a.stop_code =1
```

Comment: No I'm actually not using aliases in my code. Initially I had tried aliases but they didn't make a difference.